# Why is it common in European airports not to display the gate for flights until around 45-90 minutes before departure, unlike other places?

Tags: air-travel, europe

https://youtu.be/wdU1WTBJMl0?t=262 mentions:

> 00:04:22: Heathrow also doesn’t display the gate for flights until around 45-90 minutes before departure. This is common in European airports, but uncommon elsewhere.

Why is it common in European airports not to display the gate for flights until around 45-90 minutes before departure, unlike other places?

---

**Note regarding the duplicate flag**: my question is about *why* it is common in European airports not to display the gate for flights until around 45-90 minutes before departure, unlike other places (or perhaps this statement is incorrect). I'm not asking for the reasons why airport authorities would do it (the YouTube video I mentioned in the question explained these reasons pretty well; tl;dw=increase shop sales+take a cut from them).

Comment: I'm not sure why it matters, from a travel perspective; all that really matters is that it is how it works in Europe vs other places.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas There are plenty of why-questions on this website, e.g. see https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=why

Comment: Asking on Aviation SE may get a more definitive response, but perhaps it may be how high volume airports juggle gates (availability, amount of time an aircraft is given from arrival at gate to departure) and, separately, a way of controlling the volume of passengers with limited space in departure areas.

Comment: @Giorgio Controlling passengers in departure areas would be off-topic at Aviation.SE.

Comment: @reirab Thanks, my question is about why it  is common in European airports not to display the gate for flights until around 45-90 minutes before departure, unlike other places (or perhaps this statement is incorrect). I'm not asking for the reasons why airport authorities would do it (the YouTube video I mentioned in the question explained these reasons pretty well; tl;dw=increase shop sales+take a cut from them).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Sorry, I deleted that comment. It was automatically generated by SE when I cast a duplicate vote for the question JonathanReez had already mentioned (which, ironically enough, resulted in a duplicate comment.)

Comment: It is not all of Europe, and it is not just airports, there are also (often the same) countries that do not announce train platforms till shortly for departure.

Comment: @AliAwan Thanks, my question is about why it is common in European airports not to display the gate for flights until around 45-90 minutes before departure, unlike other places (or perhaps this statement is incorrect). I'm not asking for the reasons why airport authorities would do it (the YouTube video I mentioned in the question explained these reasons pretty well; tl;dw=increase shop sales+take a cut from them)

Comment: It may be a cultural thing. If you look at trains, Swiss trains have their platforms assigned months in advance and they are shown on timetables. French trains have their platforms displayed 20 minutes before departure, sometimes less. Whether that is a cause or effect of punctuality is left as an exercice for the reader :-)

Comment: Many airports in Europe are land constrained. In the case of Heathrow, that means that there are not enough gates to assign them in advance of landing (and so departure gates are not known either). At T5 they have something like a 95% good guess where your flight will depart three hours ahead, and the lounge will be happy to tell you if you ask. Although many airports are happy to post dozens of gate changes (NRT springs to mind) perhaps in Europe it's felt best to avoid the confusion of gate changes. UK airports often have a one-way flow onto piers which make gate changes difficult to handle.

Comment: One thing I wonder: who assigns gates?  In the US, I believe that normally the airline "owns" their gates, and can plan well in advance which flight will use which gate.  It could be that in some other places, the airport owns the gates and decides how they are assigned to flights - since the airport doesn't control the airline timetables, this would make it less possible to assign them in advance.

Comment: @JonathanReez Regarding your close vote as duplicate: My question is about why it is common in European airports not to display the gate for flights until around 45-90 minutes before departure, unlike other places (or perhaps this statement is incorrect). I'm not asking for the reasons why airport authorities would do it (the YouTube video I mentioned in the question explained these reasons pretty well; tl;dw=increase shop sales+take a cut from them)

Answer (score 8):

Most European airports have extensive shopping areas immediately after security.  Not announcing gate assignments gets travellers to stay in the shopping area rather than going to their gate.

Comment: American airports don't have extensive shopping areas?

Comment: Not concentrated right after security the way European airports do.  (This is largely because most European airports have a much larger percentage of flights outside their customs zone (especially back when they were built), and hence there is the advantage of duty-free shopping.)

Comment: This is evident especially in low-cost airports like Stansted or Gatwick. They keep the gate unannounced for a very long time eventhough the traffic there is not *that* large.

Comment: Do you have a source for this, or is it just an educated guess?

Comment: Announce is not the same as display.

Comment: Airports in Australia, or Japan, or China have plenty of shopping areas as well.